# How to change the name of input checkbox with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to change the name of input checkbox with jQuery?

I tried :

```
$('input[name="INPUT_NAME"]').prop('name', 'INPUT_NAME['+ id +']');

$('input[name="INPUT_NAME"]').attr('name', 'INPUT_NAME['+ id +']');
```

Note : i absolutely need to get INPUT_NAME with [ID] to tag it and make difference between multiple same input checkbox inside the same form.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: could you show relevant html code too?

Comment: What is wrong? For me $('input[name="INPUT_NAME"]').attr('name', 'INPUT_NAME[1]'); works

Comment: Is there any browser relevant issue?

Comment: [I don't understand what isn't working](http://jsfiddle.net/ehUGW/1/)

Comment: May I suggest you reconsider your strategy?  What are you [really trying to do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Maybe the OP is missing to wait until the dom is ready?

Comment: @MichaelWalter could be an other possibility as we don't know how OP is using his snippet

Comment: Here the HTML code :

    `<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="INPUT_NAME[]" value="1" id="1">
    &nbsp;LABEL
    </label>`
    
This code is show with and whitout javascript. The same method works well with input text and radio.

Comment: Pff! 1h on this.. INPUT_NAME[] appear in HTML with AND whitout JS. 'input[name="INPUT_NAME"]' have to be 'input[name="INPUT_NAME[]"]'..    http://jsfiddle.net/VJdEs/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to name your inputs using their id, then you can do

```
$('input[name="INPUT_NAME"]').attr('name', function(){
     return 'INPUT_NAME['+ this.id +']'
});
```

But really, there is no good reason I can imagine to do such a thing.

Comment: seems fair enough, i'd say